# Exclude Development URL from IIS rewriting rule

Tags: iis, url-rewriting, url-routing, iis-7.5, url-rewrite-module

I have a IIS URL - re-writing rule that makes sure all the urls have www. -

```
<rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
          <match url="*" />
          <conditions>
            <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" negate="true" />
          </conditions>
          <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

This works in production the way I want it to.

However I have a local version of my website set up on my development machine that looks like http://mydomain.local

When I run my local version of the website and go to mydomain.local I get redirected to www.example.com

How can I make the rule ignore my local development URL?

Comment: Add a rule on top of this to do nothing for "mydomain.local", or add another condition to do the same.

Comment: @LexLi how? can you post an example please

Answer (score 0):

You can try to add a condition to ignore the local development URL.

```
<rule name="Add www" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">
      <match url="*" />
      <conditions>
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="www.example.com" negate="true" />
        <add input="{HTTP_HOST}" pattern="http://mydomain.local" negate="true" />
      </conditions>
      <action type="Redirect" url="https://www.example.com/{R:1}" />
</rule>
```

Best regards,

Sam